# Install @types (typings) from own github?

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-install, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

I've sent a pull-request to DefinitelyTyped, but until they accept it, how do I use it in my npm packages?

Using [`typings`](https://github.com/typings/typings) is one way, e.g.: this works:

```
"async": "github:MyUserName/DefinitelyTyped/types/async/index.d.ts#patch-4",
```

---

But is there another way, using just [npm](https://www.npmjs.com), and not the deprecated & abandoned [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) project?